# Use mixin inline in Jade

Tags: html, pug

I am trying to use a mixin in the middle of a line of jade like this...

```
p some paragraph text !{ 'this'+'works' } but !{ +myMixin() } breaks it!
```

But it doesn't work. I can't figure out how to reference a mixin in the middle of a line of jade. Is it possible?

Comment: I am afraid that you can't do it as Jade mixin is a block component and therefore needs to be treated as any other block e.g. p, div etc.

Answer (score 17):

You need special way to use jade mixins inline:

```
p.
  Hello I'm using #[+jadeMixin(param)] inline.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to put a mixin in a sentence like that.
What you can do is include [blocks](http://jade-lang.com/reference/mixins/) inside the mixin and use [pikes |](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/) for plain text.

```
mixin myMixin()
  strong
   block

p This is a sentence 
  +myMixin()
    | with bold text
  |  and this is the rest of it
```

Which will render:

```
<p>This is a sentence <strong>with bold text</strong> and this is the rest of it</p>
```